# How to restore the disk space after deleting syslog file with 18 Gb?

Tags: 20.04

I've deleted `syslog` file in `/var/log` after my root disk was running out of space. Then restart the PC. The disk still having the same amount of space occupied but the syslog now have 146 kb.

This is the free space and it supposed to have 20Gb:

[image: Files View]

This is other picture showing the space that actually is occupied:

[image: Disk Usage View]

This is the output of lsblk:

[image: lsblk command]

**df -h:**

[image: df -h]

How can I solve this problem? I'm very new in ubuntu.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include a few more details? There's a bit of ambiguity in what you're asking. Please let us know: (1) how you know the space is not being freed (2) whether Ubuntu is installed in a VM or on "bare metal".

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled how your syslog file could arrive at 18 GB. Is it possible that you have only *moved* the log, without actually deleting it?

Comment: How did you delete the log file? Did you do it in "Files" by pressing the [Delete] key? If so, you may have to empty your rubbish bin.

Comment: I opened a new terminal and use **sudo nautilus**, then find the location, right click to the file move to trash, and finally I emptied the trash

Comment: My guess is this is a VM with a virtual disk that you have increased the size of the disk but not the size of the filesystem.  You use the tune2fs command to increase the filesystem so research that. If you add the output of `lsblk` command to the question we can confirm the position and perhaps provide the precise command to solve it

Comment: There's still a system logging process with log file open, writing data at 18Gb+. Reboot your system.

Comment: That is the weird thing, I rebooted the system a couple of times.

Comment: I suggest you try to find this missing log file. `sudo find / -size 1G` should find it. Then use a `sudo rm /path/to/file/filename ` to remove it

Answer (score 0):

So what do we know?

1. The root partition sda6 is about 46GB
2. The root filesystem is about 20GB
3. This suggests that the filesystem can be extended to use all 46GB

If the above is the full picture then the command `resize2fs /dev/sda6` should solve it.

Good luck

Comment: Didn't work.  **The filesystem is already 12207031 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!**. The thing is that after I delete that file should have been freed 18 Gb and somehow it didn't, is like the file still existing.

Comment: There is something inconsistent about the information you have posted. The picture shows the root partition is nearly full and is about 20GB in size. The items under root add up to that 20GB. There is nowhere for a 18GB file to be. The largest part of the items under root is about 10GB. /var is only about 5GB in size. Are you sure the file you deleted wasn’t 18MB? It might help if you add the output of `df -h` to your question. The number of 4k blocks is consistent with the near 46GB shown by lsblk.

Comment: That is the craziest thing. I have 48.9 GB in the root partition as is shown in the first picture. A file called syslog with 18GB stared to fill up the disk and I deleted it. Then I restart the system and I had the same space occupied and the file wasn't there anymore. I opened the disk usage and the second picture shows I have 20.6 GB  of the 48.9GB, but it is false because when I executed `df` command says the following **1K-blocks:47798728; Used: 41841388; Available: 5940956**. I really don't understand this.

Comment: `df -h` will give you the human readable version of `df` which is hard to interpret

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this:
as a root user execute:
`cd /root/.local/share/Trash/files/`
`ls -l` to see the size and the syslog file was there.
**To delete it:**
`rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/files/syslog`